# SSD TRIM support on RAID-1 array through Intel RST

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-1, trim, intel-rst

I'm making the jump from HDDs to SSDs on my home desktop, and I'd like to retain a basic level of redundancy (RAID-1) like what I have with my HDDs.

Right now, I'm using Intel's RAID controller on my motherboard (Asus Z-87A, Intel Z87 controller), and the array works just fine for my uses (yes, I'm aware motherboard-based RAID setups aren't as nice as a dedicated RAID card, but I didn't have the money for a dedicated card when I built this computer)

My concern, however, would be whether or not it would be possible to use TRIM on these drives while they're in an array.

Does anyone know if Intel's SATA/RAID controllers (specifically the Z87) supports TRIM on drives in a RAID1 array?

Comment: run TrimCheck to see if it works: http://files.thecybershadow.net/trimcheck/ Intel treid to enable it for RAID0, but I have no idea if they ever enabled it for RAID1

Comment: @magicandre1981 While I'd like to do that, I haven't set up the array yet. I don't want to set it up and start using it, only to find that TRIM doesn't work and I need to find another option.

Comment: unfortunately if nobody tests it we can never see if Intel added it or not.

Answer (score 1):

Intel RST RAID1 still does [NOT](http://rodi.sk/misc/intel-rapid-storage-technology-ssd-intel-535-240gb-raid-1-benchmark/) support TRIM. Test with Driver version 14.8.0.1042. TrimCheck: i waited 60 minutes, reboot did not help.

Comment: Yeah, [Intel says](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/software/000006462.html?wapkw=trim+ssd) straight-out it's RAID0 only: "Trim functionality in *RAID 0 is supported* with Intel® Rapid Storage Technology (Intel® RST) version 11.0 or greater, beginning with the Intel® 7 Series chipset."

Answer (score 0):

Intel motherboards using the C600 chipset are the only ones to support TRIM in RAID1, [as per Intel's IRSTe product brief](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/rapid-storage-technology-enterprise-brief.html). For consumers, that means only X299 or X399 boards.