# How to TRIM ssds in RAID 1 on Windows 10 (1903)?

Tags: ssd, raid, trim

I use 2 Samsung 860 pro 1TB disks in RAID 1 ([Intel RST](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/28966/Intel-Rapid-Storage-Technology-Intel-RST-User-Interface-and-Driver?product=55005) ver. 17.2.4.101) on a [Dell Precision 3620](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/04/precision-t3620-workstation/prec_t3620_om_pub/system-setup?guid=guid-a0100bf3-30e3-471a-8d1a-a77c0e46345f&lang=en-us) (i7-6700).

The write performances have degraded terribly.

Blanking and reinstalling everything is [a method](https://www.dell.com/support/article/ch/fr/chbsdt1/sln301552/solid-state-drives-in-irst-raid-1-may-have-degraded-performance?lang=en) but would take me couple of days as it is a fully loaded box with licences.

Is there a way to send a TRIM command? Or how can I setup a RAID 1 with TRIM working? (It seems that TRIM commands with **e**RTS are only compatible with Intel ssds)

Thank you.

PS: This question is different from possible duplicate question, because Intel RST evoluated in 4 years and Windows 10 may now support it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSD TRIM support on RAID-1 array through Intel RST](https://superuser.com/q/1019069/83694)

Answer (score 0):

[Samsung Support: How Do I use TRIM?](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/support/faqs-03/)

Ed. Note: ***Make a backup first, then verify it matches the source volume. Make another backup, and verify it matches the source volume.***

[Win7/Win server 2008 or later version]
-FAT32 is not supported; NTFS is supported
-TRIM cannot be done, but Enable/Disable is possible.
-Enable TRIM in Windows : fsutil command
   a. Go to All programs > Accessories > Right-click Command Prompt, and then run with administrator privileges.
   b. Enter fsutil behavior query DisableDeleteNotify, and press Enter -> "DisableDeleteNotify = 0" means Trim is enabled.
   If it is not working, enter fsutil behavior set DisableDeleteNotify 0, and then press Enter to make it work.

Comment: It is not working with Raid 1: `The volume optimization operation requested is not supported by the hardware backing the volume.`

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but this problem has bothered me for years already, and it's the reason I never built a raid1 SSD machine. However, today a possible solution for you problem crossed my mind. Perhaps it would be possible to take out one of your ssd's. The array would go into degraded mode with only one drive. Take the removed drive to another machine with AHCI support and format the drive there and TRIM it. Put it back and rebuild the array from the second disk of the degraded array. Repeat the process with the second drive. Be warrned, I have never done this, but perhaps it is possible?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Please do not suggest things you have not tried yourself as answers, instead comment on the original post so that the poster sees it, and then he can tell afterwards if it was successfull.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1138601)

Comment: Thank you for the idea. :) Actually, the only solution I found was to 1) transfer everything to a secondary array. 2) Format the main array 3) Copy back the data.